# Gradient Descent in python implementation issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Hey I am trying to understand this algorithm for a linear hypothesis. I can't figure out if my implementation is correct or not. I think it is not correct but I can't figure out what am I missing.

```
theta0 = 1
theta1 = 1
alpha = 0.01
for i in range(0,le*10): 
    for j in range(0,le):
        temp0 = theta0 - alpha * (theta1 * x[j] + theta0 - y[j])
        temp1 = theta1 - alpha * (theta1 * x[j] + theta0 - y[j]) * x[j]
        theta0 = temp0 
        theta1 = temp1

print ("Values of slope and y intercept derived using gradient descent ",theta1, theta0)
```

It is giving me the correct answer to the 4th degree of precision. but when I compare it to other programs on the net I am getting confused by it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: typically you iterate until e certain error measure is smaller than a prescribed maximal error. I don't see it here.

Comment: I'm aware of that but I was trying to implement it quickly. I assumed running the loop for over 10 times or 100 times would do it.

Comment: the progress you obtain also depends on alpha. There might be alpha values and problems where you could achieve convergence within the first 10 or 100 steps. But in general this might be difficult to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of the **Gradient Descent** algorithm:

```
import numpy as np

cur_x = 1 # Initial value
gamma = 1e-2 # step size multiplier
precision = 1e-10
prev_step_size = cur_x

# test function
def foo_func(x):
    y = (np.sin(x) + x**2)**2
    return y

# Iteration loop until a certain error measure
# is smaller than a maximal error
while (prev_step_size > precision):
    prev_x = cur_x
    cur_x += -gamma * foo_func(prev_x)
    prev_step_size = abs(cur_x - prev_x)

print("The local minimum occurs at %f" % cur_x)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll run it and get back to you.